# How to make a raster layer transparent via MapServer WMS

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, wms, cartography, mapserver

I loaded a PostGIS raster data through OpenLayers and MapServer.

The code inside the OpenLayers is as following :

```
localWMS = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
    "Local WMS layers",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/MapServer/raster.map",
    {
        layers: 'polygon',
        transparent: true,
        alpha:true
    },
    { 
        projection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        units:'m',
        isBaseLayer: false
    }
);

map.addLayer(localWMS);
```

And here is my map file, I already set opacity to each class of the layer but nothing happens:

```
LAYER
    DATA "PG:host=*** dbname=*** schema=public table=london where='rid=3' mode='1'"
    NAME "postgis"
    PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
    PROCESSING "NODATA=-9999"
    STATUS DEFAULT
    TYPE RASTER
    UNITS METERS
    CLASS
      NAME "Minor Impact"
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 0 AND [pixel] < 1.29525335532 )
      STYLE
        ANGLE 360
        OPACITY 50
        COLOR 122 182 245
        SYMBOL 0
        WIDTH 1
      END
    END
    CLASS
      NAME "Moderate Impact"
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 1.29525335532 AND [pixel] < 2.59050671063 )
      STYLE
        ANGLE 360
        OPACITY 50
        COLOR 76 230 0
        SYMBOL 0
        WIDTH 1
      END
    END
    CLASS
      NAME "Severe Impact"
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 2.59050671063 AND [pixel] < 5.69911476339 )
      STYLE
        ANGLE 360
        OPACITY 50
        COLOR 252 228 91
        SYMBOL 0
        WIDTH 1
      END
    END
    CLASS
      NAME "Catastrophic"
      EXPRESSION ([pixel] >=5.69911476339 )
      STYLE
        OPACITY 30
        COLOR 232 16 20
      END
    END
END
```

The map looks like following :[image]

Then, I tried to set one of the opacity to less than 1, the red color just disappeared. 
[image]

But if I set the Opacity of the Layer to 50

```
LAYER
    DATA "PG:host=*******************'"
    NAME "postgis"
    PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
    PROCESSING "NODATA=-9999"
    STATUS DEFAULT
    TYPE RASTER
    OPACITY 50
    UNITS METERS
```

Even more strange map appeared. 
[image]

Does anyone know what's the problem about that? Or Does anyone know the proper way to set a transparent raster layer via MapServer?

Comment: May be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653607/how-do-you-get-transparent-background-in-a-layer-with-umn-mapserver & http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44023/how-to-colour-polygons-with-a-completely-transparent-fill-using-mapserver

Comment: What is the Mapserver version and the image type you requested on output jpeg or png?

Answer (score 2):

probably what you need is to set both OFFSITE and TRANSPARENCY in the layer section, something like this:

```
LAYER
NAME 'Raster'
TYPE RASTER
CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
CONNECTION "user=postgres password=... dbname=... host=..."
DATA "bytea FROM rasters"
STATUS OFF
OFFSITE 0 0 0
TRANSPARENCY 100
END
```

being OFFSITE the color you want to be transparent and TRANSPARENCY which controls the transparency level.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I set OPACITY in the mapfile for the entire layer (not for each style). Not sure what the OFFSITE does (I don't use that). Like this:

```
LAYER
DATA "PG:host=*** dbname=*** schema=public table=london where='rid=3' mode='1'"
NAME "postgis"
PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
PROCESSING "NODATA=-9999"
STATUS DEFAULT
TYPE RASTER
OPACITY 50

UNITS METERS
CLASS
  NAME "Minor Impact"
  EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 0 AND [pixel] < 1.29525335532 )
  STYLE
    ANGLE 360
    COLOR 122 182 245
    SYMBOL 0
    WIDTH 1
  END
END
...
```

Then in your OpenLayers (javascript) you set the layer to transparent:

```
 var mapParams = {
                  'layers': 'postgis',
                  'transparent': true
                   }
 var layer_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                mapParams['layers'],
                serverURL,
                mapParams
            );
 map.addLayers([layer_wms]);
```

Comment: I tried the same thing, but the result looks like the 3rd figure. Really Strange.

Comment: The best solution is just CHange the opacity:0.5 to the OpenLayer Code and It works.